# PHP mkdir - throwing error "File exists"

Tags: php, mkdir, rmdir

I am currently working through the **Passbook** section of **iOS6** By Tutorials by the team at raywenderlich.com, and am getting the following errors in my PHP:

> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/Pass.php on line 26
>
> Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: File exists in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/Pass.php on line 26
>
> Warning: rmdir(/tmp/50c8d11c60538/..) [function.rmdir]: Directory not empty in /xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/Pass.php on line 54

The code in my class for this is as follows:

```
class Pass
{
    private $workFolder = null;
    private $ID = null;

    var $content = null;
    var $passBundleFile = null;

    private function copySourceFolderFilesToWorkFolder($path)
    {
        // recurse over the contents and copy files
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
                        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $name => $fileObject)
        {
            if (is_file($name) && substr($fileObject->getFileName(), 0, 1) != ".")
            {
                copy($name, $this->workFolder."/".str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
            }
            else if (is_dir($name))
            {
                mkdir($this->workFolder."/".str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
            }
        }
    }

    // delete all auto-generated files in the temp folder
    function cleanup()
    {
        // recurse over conrents and delete files
        $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($this->workFolder),
                        RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST);

        foreach ($files as $name => $fileObject)
        {
            if (is_file($name))
            {
                unlink($name);
            }
            else if (is_dir($name))
            {
                rmdir($name);
            }
        }

        rmdir($this->workFolder);
    }

    function __construct($path)
    {
        assert(file_exists($path."/pass.json"));

        $this->ID = uniqid();

        $this->workFolder = sys_get_temp_dir()."/".$this->ID;
        mkdir($this->workFolder);
        assert(file_exists($this->workFolder));

        $this->copySourceFolderFilesToWorkFolder($path);

        $this->readPassFromJSONFile($this->workFolder."/pass.json");
    }

    // cleanup the temp folder on object destruction
    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->cleanup();
    }
}
```

And am instantiating an instance with:

```
$coupon = new Pass("pass/source");
```

I have tried uploading the sample code supplied with the book and get the same errors.

I have posted this on the relevant forum, however no one has replied as yet, and would like to get to the bottom of this before moving on.

Thanks,
Nick

Comment: i think there should be `else if (!is_dir($name))` since the error u\you have there is beacuse you already have a dir with that name

Answer (score 1):

Your first if tests for '.' and '..' but it will be false and go to the else. And '.' and '..' are directories. So it tries to create a directory called '.', Which already exists.

```
if (is_file($name) && substr($fileObject->getFileName(), 0, 1) != ".")
        {
            copy($name, $this->workFolder."/".str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
        }
        else if (is_dir($name))
        {
            mkdir($this->workFolder."/".str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
        }
```

Fix by doing this:

```
if($name == '.' || $name == '..'){// ignore '.' and '..', but not hidden files
continue;
}
if (is_file($name))
            {
                copy($name, $this->workFolder."/".str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
            }
            else if (is_dir($name))
            {
                mkdir($this->workFolder."/".str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks Michael, however that did not work - throwing up the same errors.

Thanks to you, I have however fixed my problems.

In the else is statement I check again that it is not a directory:

```
else if (is_dir($name) && substr($fileObject->getFileName(), 0, 1) != ".")
```

As for the remove directory error, I simply had to add an extra method in which I would send a message to, checking if the directory is empty before trying to remove it.

Many thanks,
Nick

Answer (score -4):

i hope this one help u
add a “@” sign in front of mkdir, so it looks like this:

```
@mkdir($this->workFolder."/".str_replace($path."/", "",$name));
```